# The "InstallPackageAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly in Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I can't run/deploy my Xamarin Android app using Visual Studio 2015. Unfortunately after copied `The "InstallPackageAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly` error comes. What should I do?

```
100% ... 41369kb of 41369kb copied
2>The "InstallPackageAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
2>System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError ---> Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output:     pkg: /data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk
2>
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<InstallPackage>c__AnonStoreyF.<>m__0(Task`1 t)
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
2>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunLoggedAsync>c__async1.MoveNext()
2>--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<StartAsync>c__async0.MoveNext()
2>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
2>   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.InstallPackageAssemblies.Execute()
2>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
2>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
2>---> (Inner Exception #0) Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError ---> Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output:    pkg: /data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk
2>
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<InstallPackage>c__AnonStoreyF.<>m__0(Task`1 t)
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
2>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunLoggedAsync>c__async1.MoveNext()
2>--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<StartAsync>c__async0.MoveNext()<---
2>
2>Done executing task "InstallPackageAssemblies" -- FAILED.
2>Done building target "_Upload" in project "MyFirstApp.csproj" -- FAILED.
2>Done building project "MyFirstApp.csproj" -- FAILED.
2>Build FAILED.
```

Comment: Does the issue still occur once you manually remove all previously installed versions of the application from your device? Check your Application Manager carefully to ensure there are no residual Xamarin components left before you try to deploy again. Note that when an install is corrupted, you app may not show its full name in Application Manager - but instead will come up as its package name (which can be seen in your AndroidManifest.xml: `manifest/@package`)

Comment: i dont understand what u are trying to say

Comment: can u explain me this in details??

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings->Manage Apps. Find your application and do Uninstall. Then find all apps starting with "Xamarin.Android API -xx Support" and uninstall them. Uninstall app "Mono Shared Runtime". Try to deploy your app again.
As  Kirill Shlenskiy said make sure you find your app. It can be under App name or just named as your app package name

Comment: Didn't work for me. Same issue as OP.  VS 2015 Update 3 with Xamarin 4.2.0.703, Xamarin.Android 7.0.1.3. Works fine in MS Sim but not actual device (both running Kitkat 4.4)

Comment: did you see all apps I mentioned? Is your phone in development mode?
Also can you rename your app to have small letter in package name "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk" to "mono.android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk". This probably will be in your manifest file

Comment: Yeah, everything xamarin/mono related is uninstalled. App is uninstalled. Name is lowercase. Deploy then puts mono runtime on the device, Xamarin.Android API-23 support, and my app, but VS fails, will not launch and debug (error above).  EDIT: actually, it seems to register my app on the device but not deploy it (it's in the app list but shows 0MB)

Comment: when it deploys I see name uppercase. Why?
 >System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError ---> Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output:     pkg: /data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk

Comment: Anyone else have ideas when this currently designated answer doesn't resolve the issue?

Comment: can you provide your VS project code? I will test it in my environment

Comment: I am having the same issue.  Works in Debug mode just fine, then I run it in release mode and get this error:
Done executing task "InstallPackageAssemblies" -- FAILED.
Done building target "_Upload" in project "Risk.Droid.csproj" -- FAILED.
Done building project "Risk.Droid.csproj" -- FAILED

I am also running it on Xamarin Android emulator

Comment: @JPHochbaum may be you can provide sample project showing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this.  I changed to a different emulator and the error went away. Now my release version will deploy, but it crashes immediately.  Old bug fixed and new one to fix!

Comment: Still sample project would help us to help you :-)